# How to abort a thread with long execution time (Oracle procedure) remoting call?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, oracle, remoting

I have a program like this

```
var tfc = new TestFacade();
var t = new Thread(() => tfc.Run());
t.Start();
```

TestFacade is a MarshalByRefObject remoting proxy class. It has a method (Run()) execute an Oracle procedure. This procedure may take at least a few minutes to complete. But in execution time, user can cancel this operation.

I tried using Abort, Suspend, ... even closing the program but the thread just stopped at the user side, the procedure still runs and create results in the server side.

Like title, How can I abort a thread with long execution time remoting call?

Comment: You should never ever call `Thread.Abort()` unless you are trying to close out of your application (or process) entirely. Aborting threads can corrupt the .NET run-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a way to solve it, use `OracleCommand.Cancel()` to stop command from Server

1. If remoting wellknow mode = **Singleton**

   - Call `OracleCommand.Cancel()` to canceling operation.
2. If remoting wellknow mode = **SingleCall**

   - Create a `static Dictionary` to store list `OracleCommand` with a name (as key  for remoting access)
   - Create a method to create `OracleCommand` and return `key`
   - Create a method to cancel `OracleCommand` with `key`
   - Create a method to remove `OracleCommand` with `key`
   - Create a method to `do operation` with `key` and `any parameter you need`

Answer (score 0):

> How can I abort a thread with long execution time remoting call?

Short answer, **you can't.**

Attempting to abort a *local* thread as no bearing on the actual long-running thread on the remote computer.

You may want to consider using `async/await`, at least it won't hog a local thread.